# Searching an array for username

Tags: php, mysql

This code is looping through an array of what is in the database, that searches the username variable against the Usernames in the database, when its found one it should break from the if else statement.

```
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
if($username = $row['User_Name']){
     echo "username found";
     echo "Logged in as ", $Username;   
     break;
    }
else
    {
    echo "not yet";
    }
}
    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
</div>
```

I am encoutering this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in H:\STUDENT\S0190204\GGJ\Logon-process.php on line 36
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: $row['User_Name'] - is this correctly? 
WRONG: echo "Logged in as ", $Username;  
Correct: echo "Logged in as ", $username; // lowercase U

Wrong: if($username = $row['User_Name'])
Correct: if($username == $row['User_Name'])

Comment: I don't see any question.

Comment: You should definitely make that check in the sql...

Comment: if($username ==  $row['User_Name']) (u used single =)

Comment: Error tells you the problem. You need to check how you get $resultSet filled.

Comment: Smth. is wrong with your sql query. Seems that the $resultSet is false

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 1):

Where you have

```
if($username = $row['User_Name']){
```

it should be

```
if($username == $row['User_Name']){
```

single equals sets, double equals tests equality, triple equals tests literal equality.

Really though, this is not the way to do it, you should include

```
 WHERE user_name = "$username"
```

in the query rather than returning all results and looping.

Also, [don't use mysql_* functions, they're deprecated and don't include built-in secure practices like passed parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1):

this

```
if($username = $row['User_Name']){
```

should be

```
if ($username == $row['User_Name']){
```

however, there's many other ways to do this.. (like the answer above for example)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid passing such a big data and searching in a loop - there is SQL for that.

Your query should look smth like:

```
"SELECT .... WHERE `User_Name` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."...."
```